# How can we read or get session timeout with jquery from web.config so that we can handle session expiry in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

How to get Session Value from webconfig through ajax call

I have tried the following code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       var sessionTimeoutWarning = 
    "<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings
    ["SessionWarning"].ToString()%>";
        var sessionTimeout = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";

        var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000;
        setTimeout('SessionWarning()', sTimeout);

        function SessionWarning() {
var message = "Your session will expire in another " + 
    (parseInt(sessionTimeout) - parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning)) + 
    " mins! Please Save the data before the session expires";
alert(message);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: And what happened (or didn't happen)? When you view that script as it arrived in the browser, does it look right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you are doing this in `MVC`; you might need to use `"@"` syntax for that. Please try this, it may be of help.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     var sessionTimeoutWarning =    @System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SessionWarning"].ToString();
     var sessionTimeout = @Session.Timeout;    
     var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000;
        setTimeout('SessionWarning()', sTimeout);

   function SessionWarning() {
     var message = "Your session will expire in another " + (parseInt(sessionTimeout) - parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning)) + 
                   " mins! Please Save the data before the session expires";
     alert(message);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create ActionMethod/Function in Controller

```
public string IsUserLoggedIn()
        {
            if (Session["UserId"] != null) // check session here
                return "true";
            else
                return "false";
        }
```

Step 2: Create ajax call . if returns true then user is logged in otherwise not.

```
function IsUserLoggedIn() {
        var lsValue = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "IsUserLoggedIn",
            datatype: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (foData) {
                if (foData == "true")
                    lsValue = true;
                else
                    lsValue = false;
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            },
            complete: function (e) {
            }
        });
        return lsValue;
    }
```